# Shutdown hangs for one minute while umounting NFS shares on kubuntu 22.04

Tags: shutdown, systemd, nfs

I am running kubuntu 22.04 on two desktop machines. I have parts of the users' home directories mounted via NFS 3 (fstab with defaults). A few months ago I started encountering problems during shutdown and reboot: The process hangs for almost exactly one minute while unmounting the NFS shares ("A stop job is running for ..."). Strangely enough, I can umount the NFS shares before shutdown from a user session without any delay.

I tried to debug the problem which is a challenge on its own to me and only found out that the hang seems to happen in the umount2()-call itself. See excerpt from an strace

```
16:22:29 umount2("/mnt/homes", 0)       = 0
16:23:30 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/run/mount/utab", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1014, ...}, 0) = 0
```

It seems to be some weird systemd job dependency, because inserting the following service into the boot sequence [Edit 5] avoids the hang most of the times [/Edit 5] at least for reboot, but not for shutdown:

```
[Unit]
Description=umount NFS shares first thing at shutdown
After=multi-user.target
Requires=remote-fs.target
Requires=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=idle
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/usr/bin/umount -a -t nfs

[Install]
WantedBy=shutdown.target
```

[Edit]
I should mention that the hang only occurs if the mounted file system was actually accessed. Having it only mounted without access doesn't result in the hang.

Output of systemctl show mnt-homes.mount

```
Where=/mnt/homes
What=storage:/nfs/home
Options=rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=192.168.2.10,mountvers=3,mountport=856,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.2.10
Type=nfs
TimeoutUSec=1min 30s
ControlPID=0
DirectoryMode=0755
SloppyOptions=no
LazyUnmount=no
ForceUnmount=no
ReadWriteOnly=no
Result=success
UID=[not set]
GID=[not set]
Slice=system.slice
ControlGroup=/system.slice/mnt-homes.mount
MemoryCurrent=163840
MemoryAvailable=infinity
CPUUsageNSec=9059000
TasksCurrent=0
IPIngressBytes=[no data]
IPIngressPackets=[no data]
IPEgressBytes=[no data]
IPEgressPackets=[no data]
IOReadBytes=18446744073709551615
IOReadOperations=18446744073709551615
IOWriteBytes=18446744073709551615
IOWriteOperations=18446744073709551615
Delegate=no
CPUAccounting=yes
CPUWeight=[not set]
StartupCPUWeight=[not set]
CPUShares=[not set]
StartupCPUShares=[not set]
CPUQuotaPerSecUSec=infinity
CPUQuotaPeriodUSec=infinity
IOAccounting=no
IOWeight=[not set]
StartupIOWeight=[not set]
BlockIOAccounting=no
BlockIOWeight=[not set]
StartupBlockIOWeight=[not set]
MemoryAccounting=yes
DefaultMemoryLow=0
DefaultMemoryMin=0
MemoryMin=0
MemoryLow=0
MemoryHigh=infinity
MemoryMax=infinity
MemorySwapMax=infinity
MemoryLimit=infinity
DevicePolicy=auto
TasksAccounting=yes
TasksMax=17999
IPAccounting=no
ManagedOOMSwap=auto
ManagedOOMMemoryPressure=auto
ManagedOOMMemoryPressureLimit=0
ManagedOOMPreference=none
UMask=0022
LimitCPU=infinity
LimitCPUSoft=infinity
LimitFSIZE=infinity
LimitFSIZESoft=infinity
LimitDATA=infinity
LimitDATASoft=infinity
LimitSTACK=infinity
LimitSTACKSoft=8388608
LimitCORE=infinity
LimitCORESoft=0
LimitRSS=infinity
LimitRSSSoft=infinity
LimitNOFILE=524288
LimitNOFILESoft=1024
LimitAS=infinity
LimitASSoft=infinity
LimitNPROC=59998
LimitNPROCSoft=59998
LimitMEMLOCK=65536
LimitMEMLOCKSoft=65536
LimitLOCKS=infinity
LimitLOCKSSoft=infinity
LimitSIGPENDING=59998
LimitSIGPENDINGSoft=59998
LimitMSGQUEUE=819200
LimitMSGQUEUESoft=819200
LimitNICE=0
LimitNICESoft=0
LimitRTPRIO=0
LimitRTPRIOSoft=0
LimitRTTIME=infinity
LimitRTTIMESoft=infinity
OOMScoreAdjust=0
CoredumpFilter=0x33
Nice=0
IOSchedulingClass=2
IOSchedulingPriority=4
CPUSchedulingPolicy=0
CPUSchedulingPriority=0
CPUAffinityFromNUMA=no
NUMAPolicy=n/a
TimerSlackNSec=50000
CPUSchedulingResetOnFork=no
NonBlocking=no
StandardInput=null
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=inherit
TTYReset=no
TTYVHangup=no
TTYVTDisallocate=no
SyslogPriority=30
SyslogLevelPrefix=yes
SyslogLevel=6
SyslogFacility=3
LogLevelMax=-1
LogRateLimitIntervalUSec=0
LogRateLimitBurst=0
SecureBits=0
CapabilityBoundingSet=cap_chown cap_dac_override cap_dac_read_search cap_fowner cap_fsetid cap_kill cap_setgid cap_setuid cap_setpcap cap_linux_immutable cap_net_bind_service cap_net_broadcast cap_net_admin cap_net_raw cap_ipc_lock cap_ipc_owner cap_sys_module cap_sys_rawio cap_sys_chroot cap_sys_ptrace cap_sys_pacct cap_sys_admin cap_sys_boot cap_sys_nice cap_sys_resource cap_sys_time cap_sys_tty_config cap_mknod cap_lease cap_audit_write cap_audit_control cap_setfcap cap_mac_override cap_mac_admin cap_syslog cap_wake_alarm cap_block_suspend cap_audit_read cap_perfmon cap_bpf cap_checkpoint_restore
DynamicUser=no
RemoveIPC=no
PrivateTmp=no
PrivateDevices=no
ProtectClock=no
ProtectKernelTunables=no
ProtectKernelModules=no
ProtectKernelLogs=no
ProtectControlGroups=no
PrivateNetwork=no
PrivateUsers=no
PrivateMounts=no
PrivateIPC=no
ProtectHome=no
ProtectSystem=no
SameProcessGroup=yes
UtmpMode=init
IgnoreSIGPIPE=yes
NoNewPrivileges=no
SystemCallErrorNumber=2147483646
LockPersonality=no
RuntimeDirectoryPreserve=no
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0755
StateDirectoryMode=0755
CacheDirectoryMode=0755
LogsDirectoryMode=0755
ConfigurationDirectoryMode=0755
TimeoutCleanUSec=infinity
MemoryDenyWriteExecute=no
RestrictRealtime=no
RestrictSUIDSGID=no
RestrictNamespaces=no
MountAPIVFS=no
KeyringMode=shared
ProtectProc=default
ProcSubset=all
ProtectHostname=no
KillMode=control-group
KillSignal=15
RestartKillSignal=15
FinalKillSignal=9
SendSIGKILL=yes
SendSIGHUP=no
WatchdogSignal=6
Id=mnt-homes.mount
Names=mnt-homes.mount
Requires=system.slice -.mount
Wants=network-online.target
RequiredBy=remote-fs.target
Conflicts=umount.target
Before=umount.target remote-fs.target
After=remote-fs-pre.target network.target network-online.target systemd-journald.socket -.mount system.slice
RequiresMountsFor=/mnt
Documentation="man:fstab(5)" "man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)"
Description=/mnt/homes
LoadState=loaded
ActiveState=active
FreezerState=running
SubState=mounted
FragmentPath=/run/systemd/generator/mnt-homes.mount
SourcePath=/etc/fstab
UnitFileState=generated
UnitFilePreset=enabled
StateChangeTimestamp=Wed 2024-02-21 11:40:25 CET
StateChangeTimestampMonotonic=10080675
InactiveExitTimestamp=Wed 2024-02-21 11:40:24 CET
InactiveExitTimestampMonotonic=9881776
ActiveEnterTimestamp=Wed 2024-02-21 11:40:25 CET
ActiveEnterTimestampMonotonic=10080675
ActiveExitTimestamp=n/a
ActiveExitTimestampMonotonic=0
InactiveEnterTimestamp=n/a
InactiveEnterTimestampMonotonic=0
CanStart=yes
CanStop=yes
CanReload=yes
CanIsolate=no
CanFreeze=no
StopWhenUnneeded=no
RefuseManualStart=no
RefuseManualStop=no
AllowIsolate=no
DefaultDependencies=yes
OnSuccessJobMode=fail
OnFailureJobMode=replace
IgnoreOnIsolate=yes
NeedDaemonReload=no
JobTimeoutUSec=infinity
JobRunningTimeoutUSec=infinity
JobTimeoutAction=none
ConditionResult=yes
AssertResult=yes
ConditionTimestamp=Wed 2024-02-21 11:40:24 CET
ConditionTimestampMonotonic=9880739
AssertTimestamp=Wed 2024-02-21 11:40:24 CET
AssertTimestampMonotonic=9880739
Transient=no
Perpetual=no
StartLimitIntervalUSec=10s
StartLimitBurst=5
StartLimitAction=none
FailureAction=none
SuccessAction=none
InvocationID=2ac4fcae15e44482b6b9b47d7e72e006
CollectMode=inactive
```

[Edit 2]
At time of umount network is still up according to systemd. See excerpt from systemd debug output:

```
[  251.503803] systemd[1]: mnt-homes.mount: Changed mounted -> unmounting
[  251.503808] systemd[1]: Unmounting /mnt/homes...
[  251.503892] systemd-journald[476]: Successfully sent stream file descriptor to service manager.
[  251.503940] systemd[3628]: mnt-homes.mount: Executing: /bin/umount /mnt/homes -c
...
[  313.206159] systemd[1]: Received SIGCHLD from PID 3628 (umount).
[  313.206172] systemd[1]: Child 3628 (umount) died (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
[  313.206197] systemd[1]: mnt-homes.mount: Child 3628 belongs to mnt-homes.mount.
[  313.206203] systemd[1]: mnt-homes.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS (success)
[  313.206206] systemd[1]: mnt-homes.mount: Deactivated successfully.
[  313.206232] systemd[1]: mnt-homes.mount: Changed unmounting -> dead
[  313.206344] systemd[1]: mnt-homes.mount: Job 1748 mnt-homes.mount/stop finished, result=done
[  313.206347] systemd[1]: Unmounted /mnt/homes.
[  313.206376] systemd[1]: mnt-homes.mount: Consumed 18ms CPU time.
[  313.206459] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Received EPOLLHUP on stored fd 22 (stored), closing.
[  313.206475] systemd[1]: network-online.target changed active -> dead
[  313.206477] systemd[1]: network-online.target: Job 1843 network-online.target/stop finished, result=done
[  313.206479] systemd[1]: Stopped target Network is Online.
[  313.206494] systemd[1]: network.target changed active -> dead
[  313.206496] systemd[1]: network.target: Job 1769 network.target/stop finished, result=done
[  313.206498] systemd[1]: Stopped target Network.
[  313.206509] systemd[1]: network-pre.target: stopping held back, waiting for: ifup@eno1.service
[  313.206512] systemd[1]: remote-fs-pre.target changed active -> dead
[  313.206514] systemd[1]: remote-fs-pre.target: Job 1886 remote-fs-pre.target/stop finished, result=done
[  313.206515] systemd[1]: Stopped target Preparation for Remote File Systems.
[  313.206535] systemd[1]: nfs-client.target changed active -> dead
[  313.206537] systemd[1]: nfs-client.target: Job 1768 nfs-client.target/stop finished, result=done
[  313.206539] systemd[1]: Stopped target NFS client services.
[  313.206549] systemd[1]: shutdown.target: starting held back, waiting for: snapd.mounts.target
[  313.206551] systemd[1]: umount.target: starting held back, waiting for: run-snapd-ns.mount
[  313.206765] systemd[1]: ifup@eno1.service: About to execute /sbin/ifdown eno1
[  313.206956] systemd[1]: ifup@eno1.service: Forked /sbin/ifdown as 3649
[  313.207014] systemd[1]: ifup@eno1.service: Changed exited -> stop
[  313.207018] systemd[1]: Stopping ifup for eno1...
[  313.207315] systemd[3649]: ifup@eno1.service: Executing: /sbin/ifdown eno1
[  313.207315] systemd[1]: Failed to read pids.max attribute of cgroup root, ignoring: No data available
[  313.207381] systemd[1]: networking.service: About to execute /sbin/ifdown -a --read-environment --exclude=lo
[  313.207501] systemd[1]: networking.service: Forked /sbin/ifdown as 3650
[  313.207557] systemd[1]: networking.service: Changed exited -> stop
[  313.207562] systemd[1]: Stopping Raise network interfaces...
...
[  313.207806] systemd[3650]: networking.service: Executing: /sbin/ifdown -a --read-environment --exclude=lo
```

[Edit 3]
It's cable based network and the link is up unchanged before and after the umount. ip a shows (valid_lft and preferred_lft vary):

```
1: lo: ...
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ...
    altname enp6s0
    inet 192.168.2.117/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global dynamic eno1
       valid_lft 851799sec preferred_lft 851799sec
```

[Edit 4]
Forcing the umount via -f or ForceUnmount=yes doesn't help.

Any ideas how to solve this or at list further analyse?

Comment: Please [edit] with `systemctl show mnt-homes.mount` . Have you tried adding a `/etc/systemd/system` drop-in for that with `BindsTo=multi-user.target` ?

Comment: @DanielT, you mean the quoted unit with BindsTo=multi-user.target added? Tried right now, didn't help :-( I added the requested output. Thank you!

Comment: I have seen similar behaviour when the network is stopped before the nfs is unmounted. The explains the 60s. That is usually a timeout. But I don't imidiately see why the network would stop before the nfs mount.

Comment: Please [edit] with `ip a`

Comment: @ChristopherPerrin: Network is still up according to systemd. I'll edit with debug excerpt.

Comment: @ordo "network-online.target" being active doesn't mean the network is up. Please [edit] with either the above or `nmcli`

Comment: @DanielT, you mean ip a at the time of the umount attempt? Another challenge :-) Actually, I know that the network is still up, because I checked on the server and the umount request is received there.

Comment: @ordo Yeah, both that and I also wanted to know whether it was over WiFi

Comment: Would you be comfortable using the `ForceUnmount=` option?

Comment: @DanielT Not really, but I tried nevertheless...

Comment: What I meant was `echo $'[Mount]\nForceUnmount=1' | sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/mnt-homes.mount.d/99-askubuntu.conf` and restarting

Comment: That's what I did (with yes instead of 1). In a different run, I "injected" the -f flag to the umount.nfs command.

Answer (score 0):

No real remedy but at least helps with the symptoms: Putting a drop-in in /etc/systemd/system/mnt-homes.mount.d/override.conf

```
[Mount]
TimeoutSec=15
```